# Using sort() to provide a list of repos

Tags: javascript, mongodb, callback

I'm making a function that will filter through some data and display results based on a count and sort the data based upon a value. In particular it is using sort() and limit() methods. My limit() method is simple and is working fine, but my sort() method isn't working. It is functioning but not the way I intend. When I use -1 it does reverse the order. But no matter what I search for (using 1), I just keep getting the same list.. Can someone help me sort this out? This is for a query of mongodb, (and just so you know, I'm doing a query of github to get a list of repos).

This is my code:

```
       let fetch = callback => {
         let cb = (err, repos) => { callback(repos) };
         Repo.find(cb).sort({forks: 1}).limit(25);
       }
```

So far it has made no difference when this was the last method - .exec(cb). When this was the last method I did not have the cb in the find method, but the function acted the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think `sort()` function isn't never implemented because result of `find()` function is returned in `cb`.
You can try use `Promise` instead:

```
let fetch = callback => {
  Repo.find().sort({folk: 1}).limit(25).then(result => {
    callback(result);
  })
}
```

---

EDIT:

```
let fetch = (username) => {
  Repo.find({username: username}).sort({folk: 1}).limit(25).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: edited comment: The results do change, but stay the same no matter what repos I look for. It seems to be adding more to my database and just sorting those results differently. However, this time with the code you shared when I do -1 the results didn't change at all. Weird huh? With my previous code when I do -1 it reverses the order somehow.

Comment: can you post what you put in repos?

Comment: I'm searching github by username and coming up with the top 25 repos.

Comment: i just have recognised that i misunderstood your question. So, you said that when you used ```-1``` in ```sort()```, it reversed list (it has done its function) and your matter is whatever you put in, it returned same list. I think problem is in your ```callback``` function. You need to check result returned from ```callback```.

Comment: So upon your advice I tried to consule.log(result) but it's not logging anything. ALso I noticed a typo in your suggestion, fork was spelled wrong haha and I had pasted it, but it's running the same anyways after I corrected the spelling. In fact I removed the whole .sort() altogether just to see what would happen and nothing changed result wise. SO I'm still confused haha.

Comment: Hey I like your idea about using username. But it won't list any repos when I do that. I think I need to sort by username. As an aside, it's repo_id: repo.repo_id, not username, but that said, I do want to sort by username so I only display the repos for the user I listed. I also need to add a unique method so it will only display the repo once if I search for the same user more than once. Right not it's adding the same user's repos every time I search for that user.

Answer (score 0):

So lastly I found an incorrect line in my mongodb schema. This is the line I made to make sure my repos were unique. The correct code for that is:  id: {type: Number, unique: true}. Note also, I was writing: repo_id: repo.repo_id. This was incorrect because it needed to be: id: id. Now the sort, limit and unique all work correctly.